# Civicrm fields in Views, present with editable fields?

Tags: custom-fields, drupal-views

is it do able to be able to present an editable fields with civicrm custom field? as I tested using it was not available for select?

update: 
Rephrasing my questions, I am trying to setup a views with the profile contact details, but some of the contact details/fields are going to be a direct editable in the views fields options, like the module we used : drupal editable fields, but its not available for civicrm fields, are we able to do something out of the box?

thank you

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand.  Could you please try editing it to be clearer?

Answer (score 4):

(edited) Thanks for triggering me to retest this module ;-)

Some quick testing on the drupal module [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) for D7 shows this now works.

Note1: site tested on also using [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) so this may be a requirement.

It worked for me for eg First Name and a custom text field and a custom radio though it only showed Value not Label for the options.

Steps:

- add/enable modules (of course)
- set View up based on civi contact (for my testing purposes)
- add new field and choose CiviCRM Contacts: Entity metadata property (editable)
- this includes a new dropdown called Metadata property where you can then select eg First Name, or a custom field
- Save field
- hey presto

Wasn't super fast in saving but that might be my dev system

Note1 if this is awesome but needs a bit of love in terms of eg multichoice Label v Value, then either the CiviCRM Views code needs a tweak or CiviCRM Entity does.

Note2 there is new work going on to extend CiviCRM Entity currently (see [blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/jackrabbithanna/civicrm-entity-upcoming-and-future-development)) so if it is something you can help fund to happen it would be good to reach out on that project.

Comment: I totally rewrote my answer based on testing and finding to my great pleasure that this WORKS ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question correctly. Have you tried the Webform-CiviCRM integration module? That might help if you click on a link in the View?

Answer (score 0):

In civicrm this is called 'inline editing'. Check out the - totes amazeballs - Phone Number Validator for an example of how this works.

In that example I built inline editing into a page, thereby sidestepping forms alltogether.

Comment: any more specific link to documentation please? thank you

Comment: maybe he meant https://civicrm.org/extensions/uk-phone-number-validator

Comment: That has it - but it's deprecated in favour of https://github.com/JohnFF/Phone-Number-Validator :)